# Proving $X_m$ is a countable set

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, set-theory

The question is as follows: Fix m $\in \mathbb{N}$, and let $X_m$ = {$f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ | $f(n) = f(n+1)$ $\forall$ $n \geq m$}, i.e. the set of all functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ which have constant value past $m$. Prove that $X_m$ is a countable set.

The way I've gone about structuring this question is s.t we know that $X_m$ is really a union of all the subsets which have constant value at $k \in \mathbb{N}$. So it would suffice to show that $X_{m,k}$ = {$f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ |$f(n) = k $ $\forall$ $ n \geq m$} is countable for a fixed k and taking the union of all these sets to prove $X_m$ is countable:

$\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} X_{m,k}$ = $X_m$

My problem arises when trying to actually prove $X_{m,k}$ is countable. Clearly $X_{m,k}$ will only have one function s.t f(n) is constant after some m, although I'm having trouble conveying this using the definition of a countable set. Any hints?

Comment: Find  a bijection from $X_{m,k}$ to $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N\times...\times \mathbb N$ ($m-1$ factors).

Comment: I thought by definition a set is countable if there exists an injection from the set to the natural numbers?

Comment: Do you know that thre sia bijection between $\mathbb N×\mathbb N×...×\mathbb N $($m−1$ factors) and $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Would it help if you noticed, that each $f\in X_m$ is, in an obvious sense, equivalent to an $m$-term natural sequence...?

Comment: What tools are you familiar with and can use? You can also do this without too much intermediate tools, but you seem to be okay with the fact that a union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Unfortunately I'm quite new to the scope of this topic so I won't be able to build off your version of the proof. From what the other commenters suggested, can I assume Xm,k is a mapping from NxNxN...xN (m times) -> N and then show this is countable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give a different solution than the one hinted in the comments, you can construct explicitly an injective function to the naturals using prime factorization.

For example, let $p_1,...,p_m$ be distinct prime numbers. Then you can define

$$G:X_{m,k}\to \mathbb{N} \quad \text{by} \quad G(f)= \prod_{j=1}^m p_j^{f(j)}. $$

If you are familiar with primes, you should be able to see why this is injective.

Comment: Ohh my goodness it clicked. This is exactly what I'm looking for haha, thank you!